# UI freezes in simple async computation

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, async-await

**Context**

I'm working on a function that will execute some actions chronologically and I want to be able to pause its execution and then resume on a button press.

**Problem**

With the code below, the UI gets freezed when the code reaches the `await Future.doWhile(() => _isTestPaused);`

**Code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample();

  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  String _text;
  bool _isTestPaused;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _text = '';
    _isTestPaused = false;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _run());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Expanded(child: Text(_text)),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _isTestPaused = !_isTestPaused),
        child: Icon(_isTestPaused ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _run() async {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      await Future.doWhile(() => _isTestPaused);
      setState(() => _text += '${count += 1}\n');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking your code at `await Future.doWhile` In fact you would be blocking even if you were not using `await` This is because dart is single threaded.

When you reach an asynchronous function dart doesn't create a separate thread, it simply goes pass the function, and whenever it is ready it tells the event loop and stands in the back of the line. Very similar to how Nodejs handles things.

You can span an isolate to run expensive operations using `compute` in `dart:async`, but I don't know if you can stop the execution of a loop by changing some state. But whatever it is you are tying to do this is probably not the right way.

Good luck

Comment: You may be able to control the execution of a loop by using a generator function. So look that up it might help you in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Future method to run the async code. Then call using Future Builder. Since flutter is single threaded, calling async directly from within, can make the app freeze.